# Can the graph of a function have more than one oblique asymptote?

Tags: calculus

> Can the graph of a function have more than one oblique asymptote?

I think there is only one or none. Am I right?

Comment: Asking about "a function" covers _a lot_ of ground.  If we look at rational functions with radicals in the numerator or denominator, we can easily contrive different "positive" and "negative" asymptotes, as with (for instance) $ \ f(x) \ = \ \frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x^2 - 1}} \ . $  Is there a particular sort of function you're asking about?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$|x|+\frac1x,$$ which has $y=\pm x$ as its oblique asymptotes.

Answer (score 1):

$y = \dfrac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}+x$ has oblique asymptotes of $y = x+1$ as $x \to +\infty$ and $y = x-1$ as $x \to -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Any hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ has two (oblique) asymptotes.